# How to we call multiple optional functions in one line?

Tags: c#, function, class, design-patterns, methods

Consider I have multiple functions in my simple server framework as shown below, It takes multiple functions like this :

```
new TestServer()
    .DOBind("ip", "port")
    .SetMaxBindTries(3)
    .SetMaxConnections(300)
    .ONBind(delegate {...})
    .ONReceiveBytes(delegate {...})
    .ONSocketStatusChanged(delegate {...})
    .ONBlaBlaBla...
```

my question:
 - How can I do something like this ? 
 - What are the "special key words" to investigate ? 
 - What kind of "class-design / design-pattern" structure should I follow ?

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: This is usually called a "fluent API".

Comment: Some good examples of fluent design in .Net are `StringBuilder` and the Linq extension methods (note your methods could be instance methods or extension methods).

Comment: it's also often referred to as method chaining.

Comment: More important question: what´s your actual *question*? Remember: SO is not a site to ask for tutorials, howtos or any other descriptive/documentational references.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Do I have to remove the "how to" from the title ? Besides what you said there is no more question type to ask. Also I can find thousands of questions similar to this question type. Thanks for feed-back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No secret keyword or design here. What happens is that each of these methods returns the instance of the TestServer (simply by returning `this`):

```
TestServer DoThis()
{
    // method code
    return this;
}

TestServer DoThat(string WithThisParameter)
{
    // method code
    return this;
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
var x = new TestServer();
x.DoThis().DoThat("my string").DoThis();
```

Apparently, as <strike>Vache</strike> dee-see wrote in the comments, this is called ["fluent API"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.23)

Comment: Life is too short to spend wondering about the weird reasons folk downvote good answers... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class TestServer 
{
    string x = "";
    string y = "";
    string z = "";

    TestServer SetX(string val)
    {
        x = val;
        return this;
    }

    TestServer SetY(string val)
    {
        y = val;
        return this;
    }

    TestServer SetZ(string val)
    {
        z = val;
        return this;
    }
}
```

then you can do it like this

```
new TestServer().SetX("blbablabla").SetY("Blablabla").SetZ("blablabla");
```